# winrm certificate authentication failed after the server's password changed

Tags: authentication, ansible, certificate, winrm

When I modify the password of the admin account, then the certificate authentication would failed, like this:
[image]

And If I rollback the change of the password,it workes well.
  I want to know if it's possible to change the password without affecting the certificate authentication? And how?
Thanks

supplementary info:

1. I use ansible to access windows through certificate authencation；
2. I imported the client certificate in the windows；
3. Created a winrm mapping as fowlloing：

> New-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\ClientCertificate -Subject
>   'root@localhost' -URI * -Issuer 05**********C -Credential
>   (Get-Credential) -Force

Answer (score 0):

I created a local account on each of my remote windows machines with admin privileges and then used that username and password to generate a certificate request.  The remote node need not be logged in to the local account for SSL to work but the account must exist and the username and password must exactly match the ones used to request the certificate.